# How to create reader for JSON file in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a JSON FILE of format like

```
{ 
    name : [
        "Karan",
         "Hemant",
         "Sanjay",
       ],
    user_id : 1,
    user_number : +9125468846 
}
```

I can use FlatFileItemReader for CSV but for this format how can i use a reader and which one I need only name and user id , in my POJO class i create two properties LIST<> name and int user_id I want to return object customer with these two properties to the processor, any idea how can I do it

Comment: Can you add another item in your example? How are json objects stored/represented in your input file? The format of your input file (http://ndjson.org, regular json objects wrapped in an array, etc) is important to correctly choose which json reader to use.

Comment: ```{ 
   "name" : [
        "Karan",
         "Hemant",
         "Sanjay",
       ], "enabled_products" : ["product1","product2"],
    "user_id" : 1,
    "user_number" : +9125468846,"user_catrgory":"I","user_account" :"accountType"
}```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a well formatted second item to see the structure of your input. Without seeing the format, it is not possible to correctly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JsonItemReader`, I guess: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/json/JsonItemReader.html

Comment: I am using it currently but it's not mapping data to those properties which I want,  I have used  ```resource(filepath).jsonObjectReader(ClassName::new).build() ```

Comment: from the docs it seems that there must be an array of items in the JSON, not just a top-level object; can you wrap it (change the JSON file) so it looks like `{ [ { name: '', ... } ] }` and see what happens?

Comment: Changing the format is not in my hand its coming through a api